# Trying to do a where filter in findOne and in Node api returns empty array when filtering by ids in loopback

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, loopback, apiconnect

Trying to do a where filter in findOne and in Node api returns empty array when filtering by ids in loopback

`https://url/api/Model1/findOne?filter={"where":{"attrs":"id"}}`
where id is exactly 24 digits long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that you simple don't have an object with that ID in that particular collection in the database. In such a case you should get an empty array.

Or you may need to find by `id` and not by `attr` - it depends on how the relevant field in your database is named.

See the docs, there are good examples there: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Where-filter.html

E.g. this:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/Books?filter={"where":{"or":[{"id":1},{"id":2}]}}
```

Note that the `id` is used and not `attr`. See what is your field in your case.